# Count occurencies of a conditional relationship between 2 dataframes and compute correlation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I want to find the relationship between elements of different yet connected data frames. Here I have a df that shows friendships: id1 is friends with id2, id3, id4, id5, id21 etc.

|  | friend1 | friend2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | id1 | id3 |
| row2 | id2 | id1 |
| row3 | id5 | id1 |
| row4 | id12 | id2 |
| row5 | id21 | id1 |
| row6 | id4 | id2 |
| row7 | id7 | id8 |
| row8 | id1 | id4 |
| row9 | id21 | id2 |
| row10 | id3 | id5 |

Here is another dataframe where it shows when someone goes to a party. For example, Id5 went to parties on 2012-02-03 and 2012-05-09.

|  | person | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | id1 | 2012-02-03 |
| row2 | id2 | 2012-05-09 |
| row3 | id5 | 2012-02-03 |
| row4 | id12 | 2012-05-09 |
| row5 | id21 | 2012-02-03 |
| row6 | id7 | 2012-02-22 |
| row7 | id5 | 2012-05-09 |
| row8 | id3 | 2012-02-22 |
| row9 | id8 | 2012-02-22 |
| row10 | id1 | 2012-02-22 |

I want to find the correlation between people attending parties depending on whether their friends attend. For example for id1:

Went to party 2012-02-03 (same day as id21, id5) and 2012-02-22 (same day as id7, id3, id8). So 2 friends on 1 occasion and 1 on another (**mean=1.5** friends when he attends a party).

I would like to see the average number of friends existing at a party for each person present in the dataset. If someone has no friends, visited no parties, or visited parties without his friends then the mean will be 0.

I tried to build this using pandas methods like value_counts/groupby and dictionaries but I lost hope along the way. Thanks in advance for any help.

Here are the constructors for the dfs:

```
index = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8', 'r9', 'r10']
data1 = {'friend1': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id4','id7','id1','id21', 'id3'],
         'friend2': ['id3', 'id1','id1','id2','id1','id2','id8','id4','id2','id5']}
data2 = {'person': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id7','id5','id3','id8','id1'],
         'date': ['2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03','2012-02-22','2012-05-09','2012-02-22','2012-02-22','2012-02-22']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, index=index)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, index=index)
```

Comment: Hi @Steven, there is one additional important consideration to construct the relationship: the list of all parties that tool place during that period (and were open to these folks), including those which none of them attended.

Comment: hey @Alex, imagine the dfs to be in fact much larger. We can consider that the list of all the parties consists of the unique elements of the date column. There are no parties that nobody attended since column person has no nan values. There is going to be at least one attendee.

Comment: thanks, @Steven, so that meet only with each other. I got it.

Comment: Sorry to interfere here the conversation ... does my answer answer the question?

Comment: I think yes, the result is identical to mine.

Comment: Check out the code in the updated answer - it's a much shorter one doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to build a dictionary with a person as key and a set with friends as value and a dictionary with parties where the value is a set of all participants. Having both of the dictionaries a loop  over all persons will collect the appropriate data and calculate the mean value:

```
data1 = {'friend1': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id4','id7','id1','id21', 'id3'],
         'friend2': ['id3', 'id1','id1','id2','id1','id2','id8','id4','id2','id5']}
data2 = {'person': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id7','id5','id3','id8','id1'],
         'date': ['2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03','2012-02-22','2012-05-09','2012-02-22','2012-02-22','2012-02-22']}

dctPersons = {}
for friend1, friend2 in zip(data1["friend1"], data1["friend2"]):
    theSet = dctPersons.get(friend1, set())
    theSet.add(friend2)
    dctPersons[friend1] = theSet
    theSet = dctPersons.get(friend2, set())
    theSet.add(friend1)
    dctPersons[friend2] = theSet
print(dctPersons)

dctParties = {}
for person, date in zip(data2["person"], data2["date"]):
    theSet = dctParties.get(date, set())
    theSet.add(person)
    dctParties[date] = theSet
print(dctParties)

dctMeanFriends = {}
for persID, setFriends in dctPersons.items():
    visitedParties = 0
    friendsAtParty = 0
    for setPersAtParty in dctParties.values():
        if persID in setPersAtParty:
            visitedParties += 1
            friendsAtParty += len( setPersAtParty.intersection(setFriends)) 
    dctMeanFriends[persID] = friendsAtParty / visitedParties if visitedParties > 0 else 0
print( dctMeanFriends )

dfMeanFriends = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dctMeanFriends, orient='index') # columns / tight
print(dfMeanFriends)
```

outputs:

```
{'id1': {'id2', 'id3', 'id21', 'id5', 'id4'}, 'id3': {'id1', 'id5'}, 'id2': {'id21', 'id1', 'id4', 'id12'}, 'id5': {'id1', 'id3'}, 'id12': {'id2'}, 'id21': {'id1', 'id2'}, 'id4': {'id1', 'id2'}, 'id7': {'id8'}, 'id8': {'id7'}}
{'2012-02-03': {'id1', 'id21', 'id5'}, '2012-05-09': {'id12', 'id2', 'id5'}, '2012-02-22': {'id7', 'id1', 'id8', 'id3'}}
{'id1': 1.5, 'id3': 1.0, 'id2': 1.0, 'id5': 0.5, 'id12': 1.0, 'id21': 1.0, 'id4': 0, 'id7': 1.0, 'id8': 1.0}
        0
id1   1.5
id3   1.0
id2   1.0
id5   0.5
id12  1.0
id21  1.0
id4   0.0
id7   1.0
id8   1.0
```

**Below an update to the code above** motivated by the desire to get the number of code lines down. This was possible after finding a way to eliminate an assignment line required only because the `set.add()` method returns `None`. This way nine lines of code could be cut down to four lines:

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'friend1': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id4','id7','id1','id21','id3'],
         'friend2': ['id3', 'id1','id1', 'id2', 'id1','id2','id8','id4', 'id2','id5']}
data2 = {'person': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id7','id5','id3','id8','id1'],
         'date': ['2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03','2012-02-22','2012-05-09','2012-02-22','2012-02-22','2012-02-22']}

dctPersons = {}
for f1, f2 in zip(data1["friend1"], data1["friend2"]):
    dctPersons[f1] = dctPersons.get(f1,[])+[f2]
    dctPersons[f2] = dctPersons.get(f2,[])+[f1]
for key, val in dctPersons.items(): dctPersons[key]=set(val)
print(dctPersons)

dctParties = {}
for person, date in zip(data2["person"], data2["date"]):
    dctParties[date] = dctParties.get(date, [])+[person]
print(dctParties)

dctMeanFriends = {}
for person, friends in dctPersons.items():
    visitedParties = 0
    friendsAtParty = 0
    for personsAtParty in dctParties.values():
        if person in personsAtParty:
            visitedParties += 1
            friendsAtParty += len( set(personsAtParty).intersection(friends)) 
    dctMeanFriends[person] = friendsAtParty / visitedParties if visitedParties > 0 else 0
print( dctMeanFriends )

dfMeanFriends = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dctMeanFriends, orient='index') # columns / tight
print(dfMeanFriends)
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution. Although since this summary doesn't seem to account for the parties which the folks didn't attend, because there were few/no friends there, I can't see how we can calculate any kind of correlation/relationship from this summary table...

```py
data1 = {'friend1': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id4','id7','id1','id21', 'id3', 'id3'],
         'friend2': ['id3', 'id1','id1','id2','id1','id2','id8','id4','id2','id5', 'sits_home']}
data2 = {'person': ['id1', 'id2','id5','id12','id21','id7','id5','id3','id8','id1','id4','no_friends'],
         'date': ['2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03', '2012-05-09', '2012-02-03','2012-02-22','2012-05-09','2012-02-22','2012-02-22','2012-02-22','2012-02-23','2012-02-22']}
friends = pd.DataFrame(data1)
meetings = pd.DataFrame(data2)

the_friends = set(data1['friend1']) | set(data1['friend2']) | set(data2['person'])
all_friends = {(i, i) for i in the_friends}
df = meetings.merge(meetings, on='date', how='left')
df.loc[:,'pairs'] = df.apply(lambda x: tuple(set([x.person_x, x.person_y])) if x.person_x != x.person_y else (x.person_x, x.person_y), axis=1)
friends.loc[:,'pairs'] = friends.apply(lambda x: tuple(set([x.friend1, x.friend2])), axis=1)
df['count'] = 1.0
df['friends'] = False
all_friends = all_friends | set(friends.pairs.unique())
df.loc[df.pairs.isin(all_friends),'friends'] = True
result = df.loc[df.friends,['person_x', 'date','count']].groupby(['person_x', 'date']).sum().reset_index()[['person_x','count']]
result.loc[:,'count'] = result['count'] - 1
result = result.groupby('person_x').mean()
result.index.name = 'friends'
result.columns = ['Mean number of friends at the party attended']
not_attended = the_friends - set(result.index.values)
for i in not_attended:
    result.loc[i, 'Mean number of friends at the party attended'] = 0.0
print(result)
```

Output:

```
            Mean number of friends at the party attended
friends                                                 
id1                                                  1.5
id12                                                 1.0
id2                                                  1.0
id21                                                 1.0
id3                                                  1.0
id4                                                  0.0
id5                                                  0.5
id7                                                  1.0
id8                                                  1.0
no_friends                                           0.0
sits_home                                            0.0
```

Comment: This solution is more "complete" in a way, as it appears to capture the people that aren't in the 1st df (people with no friends), but exist on the 2nd df. @Claudio solution only computes for the people present in the 1st df. I picked it as the most helpful though as it was computationally much faster (2 seconds) than yours (20 minutes) for my dataset. Thank you both for your solutions :)

Comment: 20 minutes! Wow. What the size of the file? Is it the dataset of all friends in the world?)) Kidding.

Comment: 50k rows for 1st df, 100k for 2nd one ;)